# Inconsistent calendar views for an O365 group calendar, events not appearing between webpart, outlook, and calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, outlook, team-sites

(fyi I'm using the Online apps)
I added a bunch of events to an outlook group calendar it's for an O365 group that is connected to it's own SharePoint Team Site, Planner, etc.  I added these events using Outlook.

The events show up in the Outlook calendar and on the SharePoint home page Event webpart:
[image: Outlook Calendar][image: Event webpart]

But if I go to the calendar view of Events via Site contents(/Events/calendar.aspx) or the all Events page (/_layouts/15/Events.aspx) neither of them contain any events that I created
[image: Calendar view][image: All events]

I'm not sure if I missed a setting but I'd like all of the events in the events list to show up consistently if anyone has and information on how I could fix this or if it is a known issue please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use? Try using Internet Explorer.

You can look at the following similar situations:

[SharePoint Online Calendar Web part only shows events when in Edit Mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185347/sharepoint-online-calendar-web-part-only-shows-events-when-in-edit-mode)

[SharePoint Events Not Showing In Calendar, But Will Show in All Events List (SharePoint 2010)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129116/sharepoint-events-not-showing-in-calendar-but-will-show-in-all-events-list-sha)